# Understanding how 〜にもかかわらず can connect to a verb

Tags: expressions

From

> **言語は時代と共に変わるにもかかわらず**、言葉遣いに気をつけないと、「日本人じゃない」と思われてしまうこともこの発表の結果を考えると、お分かりいただけるでしょう。

Consider the first part:

> 言語は時代と共に変わる**にも**かかわらず

which I'm assuming means

> Despite language changing over time, ...

**Question:** How is it grammatical for にも (which I'm assuming is just に+も) to follow 変わる? I was under the impression that に can only follow nouns. Is there an implicit nominalizing の before the に that's getting dropped? E.g.

> 言語は時代と共に変わる**の**
>
> As for language, **the fact** that it changes together with the times

So that the whole phrase could translate (literally) as something like:

> 言語は時代と共に変わる**のにも**かかわらず
>
> As for language, despite *even* (も) **the fact that** it changes together with the times, ...

Is this what's going on with this expression?

Comment: How do you feel about ~に違いない or ~に決まっている?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[に](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/%E3%81%AB/#jn-166083) can follow verbs:

> ［格助］名詞、名詞に準じる語、**動詞の連用形・連体形**などに付く。

In the examples, the verbs are in 連体形.

So it's not necessarily の (or other expressions meaning *that*) omitted, but your understanding is fine.

---

When using na-adjectives, you would actually need の.

- x 静かなにもかかわらずパワフルなPC
- o 静かなのにもかかわらずパワフルなPC *A PC that is powerful despite being quiet*

An alternative is to use the stem: 静かにもかかわらず (this may be the most common)

For i-adjective, using の looks much less common.

- o 美しいにもかかわらず *despite being beautiful*
- △/x 美しいのにもかかわらず

Comment: Is there any subtle nuance conveyed when using 静かにも vs. the more verbose 静かなのにも? Perhaps the latter is stiffer or more formal?

Comment: @George To me, they are the same. Yet another option 静か**である**にもかかわらず may be more formal.